# Database of top researchers by keyword

Tags: website, databases

I am looking for a database/web-service that allows me to find the *top* researchers (e.g., by number of citations) in a specific field (e.g., by keywords such as *nutrigenomics*). I once used it but for some reasons I am not able to retrieve it.
I am **not** looking for the Highly Cited Researchers list from the Web of Science Group.

Comment: Google Scholar?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/).
2. Search for `label:discipline` (such as "`label:nutrigenomics`").
   If the discipline contains more than one word, then use an
   underscore to separate the words (e.g.
   "`label:international_relations`").
3. Click on "Profiles" in the menu.
4. The result should be a list of scholars (who have set up Google
   Scholar profiles) within the selected discipline, sorted by citations. [Like here](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:nutrigenomics).

Comment: Thank you but the web service I am talking about consider many more researchers and it is not influenced by the "labels", rather on the topics of the published papers.